# When I get a text from an unknown number to my Google Voice number, how do I add the person as a new contact (using Hangouts)?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, google-voice, google-hangouts

I use a Google Voice number as my primary number, which has the nice benefit of allowing me to see texts pop up as Hangouts when I have Gmail open.

[image: Hangouts side bar][image: SMS hangout with an unknown number]

I can't figure out how to add a new contact from the Hangouts window when I get a text from an unknown number. I know I can always copy and paste the number into the new contact form, but I'm hoping there's an easier way. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: I can't find a single way to do it with just the Hangouts app. Of course, it's stupidly simple with my Google Voice Chrome extension. I'd also consider jumping into Gmail (because I have GV email me all my SMS messages too) and create the contact from there. I don't see a way to do it just from the Hangouts app.

Comment: Thanks @Al E., that's a good idea to jump into the email. You're saying it's easy to do from your Google Voice Chrome extension? Could you post a link to that extension please?

Comment: I should say "used to be stupidly simple". Now that I use the Hangouts app  for my SMS, the Google Voice extension doesn't give me my incoming SMS messages.